# Инициализация объектов в JS

Tags: javascript, объекты, javascript-events

Скорее всего и заголовок данного вопроса выбран не правильный!
Есть код

```
const $ = {};

$.modal = function (options) {
  return {
    close() {
      //какой-то код
    },
  };
};

const priceModal = $.modal({
  property: {
    handler() {
      priceModal.close();
    },
  },
});
```

В коде ошибок нет! Вопрос: как в момент присвоения значения в переменную "priceModal" мы тут же можем с ним работать? Объясните пожалуйста как это работает?

Вот если было бы так как внизу, вопросы бы не возникали:

```
const priceModal = $.modal({
  property: {
    handler() {
      //какой-то код, не важно
    },
  },
});

priceModal.какой-то_там_метод_в_полученный_в_результате_присвоения()
```

Объясните пожалуйста как это работает?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как в момент присвоения значения в переменную "priceModal"

Вызов `priceModal.close()` происходит не перед присвоением `priceModal`, а позже, когда вызывается метод `handler`. К этому времени, переменная `priceModal` имеет присвоенное значение. Так что все в порядке.